# Как сохранять данные в LocalStorage при переполнении памяти в 5мб?

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs, localstorage

как не потерять данные которые сохраняются в localStorage? Пользуюсь Angular-localStorage, который при переполнении памяти просто не сохраняет данные. Может есть какие то способы при переполнении сохранять в куки или что то подобное?
Понимаю что в LocalStorage никто не хранит данные большого объема, но увы в данной ситуации требуется.

Comment: Это ограничение браузера, а не `angular-localStorage`. К сожалению, увеличить размер localStorage (обычно в 5BM) нельзя. По кукам тоже есть ограничения. В Хроме есть поддержка Web SQL, которое позволяет хранить больше, но решение не кроссбраузерное.